# Is it possible to include a shared calender from Exchange in the calendar app on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, calendar, exchange

I am trying to add a shared Exchange calendar to my Mac Calendar app. The shared calendar shows up in the Outlook calendar, but how do I add it to the Mac Calendar?

Answer (score 28):

Here's the way that worked for me:

1. With iCal open go to the menu bar at the top of the screen and select iCal, it's to the right of the Apple Symbol in the upper left corner.
2. Select Preferences
3. Once the Preferences window comes up select the Accounts section then select the Exchange account to bring up its information.
4. Now select the Delegation tab.
5. Under the list is a + sign. Click this to add a calendar.
6. Begin typing the user's name as above and the auto-completion will begin. Once you've found the correct user's name select it to add it under the Users column.
7. Under Accounts I can access: you will now see that user's name. You can enable or disable their calendar from displaying by checking or unchecking the boxes under the Show header.

I found these instructions from the [USC website](http://pt.usc.edu/uploadedFiles/USC_Physical_Therapy/Subpages/Content/About_The_Division/IT_Support_Pages/Sharing%20Exchange%20Calendars%20iCal.pdf).

Comment: Still works in 2022. [Lastest memento](https://web.archive.org/web/20180403163826/http://pt.usc.edu:80/uploadedFiles/USC_Physical_Therapy/Subpages/Content/About_The_Division/IT_Support_Pages/Sharing%20Exchange%20Calendars%20iCal.pdf) of the USC instructions and [official Apple docs](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/icl27527/11.0/mac/12.5) plus caveat [About using Exchange calendars on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/icl28029/11.0/mac/12.0).

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and just figured it out.

Here are the steps:

1. Login to Outlook Web Access (the web interface for your Exchange Server).
2. Click on public folders (for me, it was all they way in the bottom left).
3. The, navigate to the public folder of your choice (I needed a calendar).
4. Right click on the public calendar and select copy from the context menu.
5. Navigate back to your own mailbox (I clicked "mail" in the lower left).
6. Right click on your own calendar and click paste (I added it to a new folder).
7. Then, return to calendar.app and refresh your calendars (View menu -> refresh or command R).
8. After doing that, the public calendar popped up along side my other calendars.

Hope it works as well for you as it just did for me!

Also, I think this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152243/how-to-view-public-exchange-calendars-from-ical).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my public folder I can't find any calendar. There are only some contacts of my organization. Now I tried to add the calendar to Outlook Web Access under the menu calendar. I can see the calendar in OWA but in my Calendar app the calendar doesn't appear (even after refresh).